# How can I store GETDATE() in a varchar, but as a datetime?

Tags: sql, datetime

When I use `INSERT INTO table varchar_field Values (GETDATE())`, the database stores the value as:

```
    Mar 19 2013 12:55PM
```

but I want to be stored as:

```
    2013-03-19 12:55:24.577
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a `varchar`?  Why not just change the datatype on the column? Your problem will be solved.

Comment: It's a config table mapping various parameters to values. I'm storing a date as the value in this case.

Comment: @AlanMarshall hopefully you're not storing `VARBINARY` ... `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),0x6869,121)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select CONVERT(varchar(50),getdate(),121)

INSERT INTO table varchar_field Values (CONVERT(varchar(50),getdate(),121))
```

As Lamak pointed out, I incorrectly left out specifying the length of the varchar

Comment: Thanks. I checked the MSDN page on DATETIME and saw the reference to CONVERT, but for some reason didn't think of passing a parameter other than it's example of time.

Comment: Please always use `VARCHAR` with a length (as in `VARCHAR(10)`), don't keep using just `VARCHAR` or you might get incorrect results. See this https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length from @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 9):

***Please stop storing your date value as a `varchar`, use the correct datatype.***

Your best solution is to alter your column to the correct datatype.

However, if you need to convert the `getdate()`, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table varchar_field
select convert(varchar(50), GETDATE(), 121)
```

Here is a [complete list of all data conversions for SQL Server](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

```
alter yourtable drop column varchar_field
```

Step 2

```
alter yourtable add column datetimefield datetime default getdate()
```

Step 3

```
select convert(varchar(50), datetimefield, 121)
from yourtable
```

This approach allows you to change formats if required, or do date math.`